# Change image when click this item on listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which containts 16 items. When I click item 1,i changed image of item 1. But   when i click item 2,image of item 1 doesn't change. I want image of item 1 back to default when item 2 is clicked. and rest same.I searched many on this web but i didn't found solution.Anyone help me?

**here my code :**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    menuitemfix = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items_fix);
    viewslide = new View(getActivity());
    textslide = new TextView(getActivity());
    imageslide = new ImageView(getActivity());

    items.add(new HeaderSection("ĐĂNG NHẬP"));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Thông báo", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_notice));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Nhắc lịch", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_prompted));
    items.add(new SectionItem("TRUYỀN HÌNH"));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Kênh ", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_live));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Lịch phát sóng", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_epg));
    items.add(new SectionItem("THƯ VIỆN"));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Rạp phim", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_movie));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Video Clip", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_video));
    items.add(new EntryItem("TV Show", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_tvshow));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Đã phát sóng", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_catchup));
    items.add(new SectionItem("BẠN BÈ"));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Danh bạ", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_contacts));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Tin nhắn", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_message));
    items.add(new SectionItem("NO NAME"));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Cổng tiện ích", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_gate));
    items.add(new EntryItem("Đăng xuất", R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_logout));
    adapter = new EntryAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //set background cho slidemenu

    viewslide.setBackgroundResource(0);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191a1e"));
    viewslide = v;
      //thay đổi icon slidemenu
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);
    iv = imageslide;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:         
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleSideMenu();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment mfragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(FacebookLoginFragment.TAGfacebook);
        if (mfragment == null) {
            addFragment(new FacebookLoginFragment(), false,
                    FacebookLoginFragment.TAGfacebook);
        }
        break;
    case 1:iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_notice_active);
            break;                  

    case 2:
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleSideMenu();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).SetTitle(menuitemfix[position - 1]);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTouchmodeAboveFull();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmentepglist = fm.findFragmentByTag(EPGEventUserFragment.TAGEPGEvent);
        if (fragmentepglist == null) {
            addFragment(new EPGEventUserFragment(), false,
                    EPGEventUserFragment.TAGEPGEvent);
        }
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_prompted_active);
        break;

    case 4:
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleSideMenu();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).SetTitle(menuitemfix[position - 1]);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTouchmodeAboveFull();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment mChannelListFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(ChannelListFragment.TAGchannel);
        if (mChannelListFragment == null) {
            addFragment(new ChannelListFragment(), false,
                    ChannelListFragment.TAGchannel);
        }   

        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_live_active);
        break;
    case 5:
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleSideMenu();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).SetTitle(menuitemfix[position - 1]);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTouchModeAbove();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment mEPGFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(EPGFragment.TAGEPGfragment);
        if (mEPGFragment == null) {
            addFragment(new EPGFragment(), false,
                    EPGFragment.TAGEPGfragment);
        }
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_epg_active);
        break;
    case 7:
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleSideMenu();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).SetTitle(menuitemfix[position - 1]);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTouchmodeAboveFull();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmentmovie = fm.findFragmentByTag(MovieNewFragment.TAGMovieNewFrag);
        if (fragmentmovie == null) {
            addFragment(new MovieNewFragment(), false,
                    MovieNewFragment.TAGMovieNewFrag);
        }

        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_movie_active);
        break;
    case 8:
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_video_active);
        break;
    case 9:
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_tvshow_active);
        break;

    case 10:
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleSideMenu();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).SetTitle(menuitemfix[position - 1]);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTouchmodeAboveFull();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmentcatchup = fm.findFragmentByTag(CatchupNewFragment.TAGCatchupNewFrag);
        if (fragmentcatchup == null) {
            addFragment(new CatchupNewFragment(), false,
                    CatchupNewFragment.TAGCatchupNewFrag);
        }   

        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_catchup_active);
        break;
    case 12:
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_contacts_active);
        break;
    case 13:
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_message_active);
        break;
    case 15:
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slidemenu_gate_active);
        break;
    case 16:
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Bạn muốn thoát khỏi chương trình?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Đồng ý",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).logout();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Từ chối", null).show();
        break;

    default:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Chuc nang nay dang duoc phat trien",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    }
           **temp_position = position;**
}
void addFragment(Fragment fragment,boolean addToBackStack,String tag)
{
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
    if(addToBackStack) ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I edit my code in onlistitemclick before switch statement:

```
        if(temp_position != 0){
            // Get icon from array in array.xml which contains name of image in drawable
        int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[temp_position],
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        iv.setImageResource(id_icon);
            }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Keep track of the previously changed image and the view (Save them in a temporary variable ) and reset it when you click on other next item, do the same for second item also

Comment: yes. I know algorithm but i can't write code exactly. You can write code to help me!

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you don't save the previous item position anywhere. You should first store the clicked item position in a variable, then when you click some other item, get the variable and set it to it's default state.

```
//your temp variable for the previous position
int tmpImagePosition;
```

then in every case of your switch statement

```
... access to your image with the position of the tmpImagePosition and set it to it's    default    

tmpImagePosition = postion; //position you get from your switch
```

Comment: You could give example code. I know algotithm but can't write code exactly

Comment: i save all previous item on OnCreate(),  "imageslide = new ImageView(getActivity());" then when click item on listview,i assigned "iv = imageslide;"

Answer (score 0):

For me It's work:

```
 //Add variable in adapter class
int first =-1; 
ImageView previous;
//then in getView
  viewHolder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
if(first!= position) //if same picture  is not same 
{
if(first!=-1) //do not work for the first time
{
    differentPosition();                    
}
}
previous = viewHolder.ivPlay; // for previous image 
 first = position;// for the position of previous image

 }
});

// then outside the getView Make method
public void differentPosition()
    {
        previous.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    }
```